# subtle noise in the background when I export from all Blenders after 2.9

Tags: rendering

I have had an issue where I am editing a 3D mesh and when I go to render as PNG, it looks fine to my eyes. But when brought into Photoshop, there is evidence of messy noise or some other graphic distortion in the transparent background. My only solution to this has been to constantly use Blender 2.9 to avoid this hassle. But a colleague said it was due to the shadow rendering on the floor element. I removed shadow cast but that didn't solve the issue. It happens to every single file that I render. I'm still a noob and am self-teaching so I probably won't even understand it if anyone answers this.
Does anyone know what significant changes happened after Blender 2.9 that could be effecting this? Or what else I can try to remove or change in order to get a clean transparent background?

Thanks !!

[image: messyexport]